# Bulk Insert Statement in SQLITE of Chrome

Tags: database, html, sqlite, google-chrome

I am not able to bulk insert in chrome inbuilt db.
I tried following methods

```
db.transaction(function(query){
  query.executeSql("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION",[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler)

   query.executeSql('INSERT INTO  cstmr_info (lst_nam  ,fst_nam ,doc,email ,mob_no ,hosp )VALUES("a","b","c","d",6256,"dcd")',[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
   query.executeSql('INSERT INTO  cstmr_info (lst_nam  ,fst_nam ,doc,email ,mob_no ,hosp )VALUES("a","b","c","d",6256,"dcd")',[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler);


  query.executeSql("COMMIT TRANSACTION",[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler);

        });
```

I tried this but it throw error

```
db.transaction(function(query){

       query.executeSql('INSERT INTO  cstmr_info (lst_nam  ,fst_nam ,doc,email ,mob_no ,hosp )VALUES("a","b","c","d",6256,"dcd"),("a","b","c","d",6256,"dcd")',[],nullDataHandler, errorHandler);

            });
```

But this is also not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transaction` function already does a transaction.

Multiple records in a single VALUES clauses are supported since SQLite 3.7.11, so you cannot rely on this being available.

Just use multiple INSERTs inside a single transaction:

```js
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cstmr_info(...) VALUES(...)', ...);
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO cstmr_info(...) VALUES(...)', ...);
});
```

Comment: But I have More than 4000 rows.wouldn't it be little slow??I have already moved this processing on web worker. Thanks

Comment: Being the *only* way that works, it's the *fastest* one.